# Erlang: module attribute

Tags: erlang, module

I am new to Erlang.
Found the following **-module** attribute declaration in an existing Erlang project:

```
-module(mod_name, [Name, Path, Version]).
```

What does mean the second parameter (list [Name, Path, Version]) here?

I haven't found any information in the Erlang reference on it.

Comment: Parameterised modules are not yet officially part of Erlang although the current distributions support them. Also to be safe, except for new, you should never call functions in a parameteised modules directly. Always use the eference returned from new.

Comment: If parameterised modules are removed though then won't new stop working?

Comment: These really should be documented somewhere officially. There are now widely used apps that use them (Mochiweb, for example). For example of their use in Mochiweb, see http://code.google.com/p/mochiweb/source/browse/trunk/src/mochiweb_request.erl

Comment: Note that with Erlang R16, to be released Feb. 27 2013, parameterized modules support is mostly removed. [You can read the details here.](http://www.erlang.org/news/35)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This defines a parameterised erlang module - one you can "instantiate" with new and then access the parameters passed by that new when executing code in your module.

A very brief overview is here:

http://myotherpants.com/2009/04/parameterized-modules-in-erlang/

Answer (score 8):

This is a parametrized module. Here is the [original paper](http://www.erlang.se/workshop/2003/paper/p29-carlsson.pdf) on it. Basically you can create instances of the module binding specific values to those variables. You can initialize one as:

```
> Mod = mod_name:new("MyName", "/path", '0.1').
```

and then call its functions as:

```
> Mod:function(...)
```

where the module parameters are also available in the function body.