# What does "new" do when called on an erlang module do?

Tags: erlang

I've seen module_name:new used in Erlang code, but there is no reference to a "new" function in the module_name module. What does "new" do?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358230/erlang-module-attribute

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is for "parametrized module": see **[here](http://yarivsblog.com/articles/2009/05/11/geeking-out-with-lisp-flavoured-erlang/)** and **[there](http://myotherpants.com/2009/04/parameterized-modules-in-erlang/)** for more details.

Comment: But they also say that this is not a standard part of Erlang? So maybe it will be removed?

Comment: This is nothing like classes. A parametrized module simply enables you to pass some parameters (common to most of the functions in the module) to functions without including them as arguments.

Removing it involves more work than leaving it as it is; so my guess it will be not removed. If it is broken because of some other changes, it might not be fixed...

Comment: Ok, so basically we shouldn't use them? It is just that I've seen them used extensively in many Erlang Open Source projects...

Comment: Well its quite hard to manage, as I need to decide if I allow users to use them in a client API. Anyway, I've added another StackOverflow question regarding this, as if it gets removed then many Erlang products will break

Comment: Since this is so widely used, why not just document this and make it standard?

Answer (score 0):

```
        'new'/2 =
    fun (_cor1,_cor0) ->
     apply 'instance'/2
         (_cor1, _cor0)
'instance'/2 =
    fun (_cor1,_cor0) ->
     {'p',_cor1,_cor0}  %%GOTCHA!!!!!
```

http://www.cnblogs.com/me-sa/archive/2012/02/16/Erlang0037.html